# herror deprecated

Tags: c, networking, glibc, gethostbyaddr

Answering [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11830514/1468366), I stumbled upon the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/herror) of a function called `herror`. It appears to be very much like `perror` except it prints errors related to some host lookup problem. The man page states that this function is “obsolete”. A function `hsterror` which could be used to turn the error number into a string without printing it is marked obsolete as well.

What I don't see is any indication as to *why* either of them is obsolete, and what *replacement* should be used instead. So what is the preferred way to turn an obscure `h_errno` error number into a user-readable string on a GNU libc linux system? Should every tiny application ship a translation table of its own, and hope that the set of possible error codes doesn't change any time soon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are obsolete because `gethostbyname*` is obsolete. Use `getaddrinfo` instead, and use `gai_strerror` for errors.

From the [`gethostbyname(3)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname):

> The  gethostbyname*()  and  gethostbyaddr*()  functions  are  obsolete. Applications should use [getaddrinfo(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) and [getnameinfo(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getnameinfo) instead.

Comment: Thanks! That message appears a little less pronounced than the one I read first. A link to the new man pages would be great, but in any case I'll accept this answer once I'm allowed to.